# If satetment: when date field is 1 month or older

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named `transactions` that has 5 fields. I am running an `update` query for column where `name` = `jane` and incrementing `transaction` by `1`. How can I use an if statement when `date_created – tran_date =  1 month` and set values to `transaction = 0`, `tran_date = 0000-00-00`, and change `date_created` to the new current date.

Query

```
UPDATE transactions SET transactions = transactions + 1, tran_date = CURDATE()  WHERE name = 'jim'
```

Create tables and set values:

```
CREATE TABLE transactions
(
  id int auto_increment primary key,
  date_created DATE,
  name varchar(20),
  transactions int(6), 
  tran_date DATE
);

INSERT INTO transactions
(date_created, name, transactions, tran_date)
VALUES
(NOW(), 'jim', 0, 0000-00-00),
(NOW(), 'jane', 0, 0000-00-00);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is using a `case` statement:

```
UPDATE transactions
    SET transactions = (case when tran_date >= date_sub(CURDATE(), interval 1 month)
                             then transactions + 1 else 0
                        end),
        tran_date = (case when tran_date >= date_sub(CURDATE(), interval 1 month)
                          then CURDATE() 
                          else '0000-00-00'
                     end),
        date_created = (case when tran_date >= date_sub(CURDATE(), interval 1 month)
                             then date_created 
                             else CURDATE()
                         end)
    WHERE name = 'jim';
```

An alternative is to do this with two separate `update`s:

```
UPDATE transactions
    SET transactions = transactions + 1 
    WHERE name = 'jim' and tran_date >= date_sub(CURDATE(), interval 1 month)

UPDATE transactions
    SET transactions = 0,
        tran_date = '0000-00-00',
        date_created = CURDATE()
    WHERE name = 'jim' and tran_date < date_sub(CURDATE(), interval 1 month)
```

I think the logic might be a bit clearer, but there is more overhead for two `update` statements.

Comment: Great and straightforward. First time working with cases and i think i will be using them alot. Would this have any effect on months like `February`, or some that are `30`days and not `31`?

Comment: @MaryCoding . . . This should work for all months.  The `interval 1 month` takes care of the number of days in the month.